# How to get the difference between two chrono dates?

Tags: date, datetime, rust

I'd like to get a "time-span" difference between today `08/11/2020` and `01/01/1970` in such format:

```
Timespan:
50 year(s) 10 month(s) 7 day(s)
```

The code below correctly calculates this for: `today - 01/01/1970`. However, it fails miserably for input like `23/12/1970` giving:

```
50 year(s) -1 month(s) -15 day(s)
```

Whereas the expected result is `49 year(s) 10 month(s) 16 day(s)`.

More dates to test:

- `09/01/1985`

  Got: `35 year(s) 10 month(s) -1 day(s)` but expected `35 year(s) 9 month(s) 30 day(s)`.
- `24/02/1936`

  Got: `84 year(s) 9 month(s) -16 day(s)` but expected `84 year(s) 8 month(s) 15 day(s)`.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "relative-delta"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["baduker"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.19"
```

Code:

```
use chrono::{NaiveDateTime, DateTime, Utc, Datelike};

fn main() {
    let date_string = "23/12/1970";
    let naive_date = chrono::NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y").unwrap();
    let naive_datetime: NaiveDateTime = naive_date.and_hms(0, 0, 0);
    let date = DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(naive_datetime, Utc);

    let years = Utc::now().year() - date.year();
    let months = Utc::now().month() as i64 - date.month() as i64;
    let days = Utc::now().day() as i64 - date.day() as i64;

    println!("Timespan:\n{} year(s) {} month(s) {} day(s)", years, months, days);
}
```

Comment: Note: `Utc::now()` could switch date in the middle of your computation. When playing with times, it's important to be very explicit about _when_ you create a new time, and avoid repeatedly creating them.

Comment: I think your question is related to the following issue and not yet implemented. https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/416 Maybe you could participate on GitHub with the maintainers.

Comment: `Utc::now().month() as i64 - date.month() as i64;` Do you expect this to be always non-negative, and if so, what kind of black magic should be responsible for that?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation does not make sense to me e.g. if today's date is 1st Nov 2021, your calculation would return 1 - 23 = -22 as the number of days. Today is my third day of learning Rust and therefore I do not have enough expertise to give you an optimized solution. However, if you assume a year of 365 days and a month of 30 days, the following solution should meet your requirement.

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

fn main() {
    // Tests
    print_diff("23/12/1970");
}

fn print_diff(date_string: &str) {
    let today = Utc::now();

    let datetime =
        DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(chrono::NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y")
            .unwrap()
            .and_hms(0, 0, 0), Utc);

    let diff = today.signed_duration_since(datetime);
    let days = diff.num_days();
    let years = days / 365;
    let remaining_days = days % 365;
    let months = remaining_days / 30;
    let days = remaining_days % 30;

    println!("{} years {} months {} days", years, months, days);
}
```

**Output:**

```
50 years 11 months 9 days
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8ca2344686e6dea9dd8a7141fbb3b88)